# Port 465 cannot send email

Tags: ssl, google-compute-engine, laravel-5.3

I set up account in google compute engine, and I use go daddy smtp 
`smtpout.asia.secureserver.net` , this works fine in my localhost but in GCE it will threw error `Connection could not be established with host smtpout.asia.secureserver.net [Connection timed out #110]` ...is port 465 with option 'ssl' is block ? ...how to enable this 465 'ssl' in GCE ?

**EDIT**
465 works fine if I use gmail account...but why using other smtp is not working ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try for Port 587 that is using TLS protocol for sending emails from Google. Google recommends using port 587 instead of 465. Also, use telnet client to check for the protocols available on your machine.

Open command prompt and type:

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
ehlo nico
```

Check for the text listed under it.
You should be getting `STARTTLS` and `CHUNKING` keyword. If not, your network is blocking these features.

For further reference [see](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2520500?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - Google Compute Engine blocks all outbound connections on ports 25, 465 and 587.

### Using standard outbound email ports on Google Compute Engine

Yattin's answer is incorrect regarding Google Compute Engine (it only answers how to send mail using gmail).

Google Compute Engine blocks all [outbound connections on ports 25, 465 and 587](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/#using_standard_email_ports) for the sake of protection against spam and abuse. The only exceptions are for outbound connections to Google's mail services like GMail or Google Apps.

### Options for outbound email on Google Compute Engine

- Use a trusted third-party mail provider like [SendGrid](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-sendgrid), [Mailgun](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun) or [Mailjet](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailjet).
- Use GMail account to send the messages. This is what you tried already based on what you have mentioned in your question.
- Use [Google Apps SMTP relay service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491) if you have a Google Apps account.
- If you already have a corporate email server and you have a VPN connection to that from your Google Compute Engine instances, you can tunnel the mail traffic to your corporate email server and let it handle the mail delivery.